# Cross-platform Python GUI framework

Tags: python, gui, cross-platform, gui-builder

I have coded a few 100 Kloc of Python, but have never yet added a GUI. Can you recommend me a GUI framework? (I am looking at you, @SteveBarnes ;-)

Must be:

- cross platform: Windows, Linux, Android, iOs & Mac
- plays well with Leaflet mapping

Nice to have:

- runs in the browser too
- free for commercial use, but I am happy with one which is free until I make $ X with it, rather than free but with fewer features, and I have to pay for some features before I begin to earn from it (which I will almost certainly never do)
- good documentation, forums, code samples, tutorials, Udemy, etc
- drag & drop GUI designer

Bonus features:

- MVC (Model, View, Controller)
- two way data binding

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) but you might also like to take a look at [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) *but I am less familiar with the latter*.
*A lot of people go with one of the bindings the QT framework but if you are planning on commercial use I would say avoid it like the plague as the licencing for the core library which you need even if the bindings are open source are a nightmare with high, annual, per dev seat, licenses required if you are looking at any commercial applications.*

To take the points one at a time:

Must be:

- cross platform:

  - Windows wxPython & Kivy = Yes
  - Linux wxPython & Kivy = Yes
  - Android Kivy = Yes, wxPython No
  - iOs Kivy = Yes, wxPython **No** at least at the moment
  - Mac wxPython & Kivy = Yes
- plays well with Leaflet mapping: wxPython = Yes, Kivy = Maybe

Nice to have

- runs in the browser too - As far as I know neither currently runs in browser.
- free for commercial use - wxPython & Kivy = Yes
- good documentation, forums, code samples, tutorials, Udemy, etc - wxPython **Yes**, Kivy Somewhat less *so in my opinion*,
- drag & drop GUI designer - for wxPython there is wxGlade, wxFormBuilder and a few others, I am not sure what there is for Kivy.

Other considerations:

- wxPython - mature, lots of support, books, etc. Native look & feel on each platform, also provides wrappers for a number of utility classes
- Kivy - Modern, new, kivy look & feel

I would encourage people to use virtual environments to test the demos for each out to see which you like & meets your needs.

Another thing that you might wish to look at is Gooey - if your existing code is argparse based and you opt for wxPython then [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) can give you an initial GUI by adding just 2 lines of code *(one being the import)*!

### Instructions for installing each including the demos

- Kivy has instructions [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html)
- For wxPython `python -mpip install wxPython` will also  install wxDemo and wxDocs utilities to download (if needed), unpack (if needed) and run the demo or show the docs.

### Some screenshots

## wxDemo

Opening Screen
[image]
wx.Slider
[image]
TextCtrl
[image]

## Kivy Showcase

Opening Screen
[image]
Sliders
[image]
TextInputs
[image]

### *Disclaimer*

Please note that the above is **my** opinion and I may be slightly biased to wxPython rather than Kivy as I have been using the former for years and I have had a couple of minor code contributions accepted.

Comment: Wow! And he is back - with a vengeance! It will, obviously, take me a while to read though this, but thank you ***very*** much. I am sure that it will be of great help to everyone who reads this question in future.

Comment: Not to question your thorough answer, but by the OPs requirements, wxPython is not acceptable due to not supporting iOS and Android.