# Castle design software

Tags: windows, simulation, visual-design, history

Sorry if this sounds rather vague. A young relative has developed a passion for castles.

I am seeking a Windows app (preferably, but will accept Linux, or even Mac) which will let one design a castle, preferably drag & drop, and walk through the result (2d is fine, just looking at the floorplan; 3d is a bonus). Bonus if it will critique the design & point out mistakes. Nice if it can the be attacked by an AI enemy to see how well it holds out.

I am looking for an ideal app, but welcome anything at all related to castles. I prefer something serious, but expect that a game might actually be the most realistic.

Comment: I imagine you're looking for [something like this](https://youtu.be/sJkXRDKdAcM). I unfortunately don't know what software was used for making that design, but maybe someone who sees this can recognize it.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I don't use YouTube, but will figure out how to contact whoever uploade dthat. Thanks !

Comment: [in this post](https://www.deviantart.com/shad-brooks/art/HONORGUARD-The-Castle-of-Morane-cross-section-730007573) that I just found, it is mentioned that he used SketchUp, which is a general purpose 3D modeling software

Comment: Thane feel free to post an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you and/or your nephew are up for a rather steep learning curve then Blender 3D Modeller can make excellent 3D castles, with walk/fly-throughs, animations, and just about everything on your list other than AI driven attacks.

**Blender itself is available 100% free for Windows, Mac & Linux.** A little research online will also give you at least one blender castle creation plug-in. Note that not all plug-ins or pre-made blend files are themselves free e.g.: https://free3d.com/3d-model/modular-castle-dungeon-creation-set-for-blender-3d-v2-7336.html is <$30.

Of course Blender can be used for a lot of other things as well - some 3D modelling companies will even accept blender files or exports to print your finished  castle.

[image][image]
[image]

There are even specific tutorials online for building castles in Blender:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWIy2OqhlTs
- https://www.blendernation.com/2018/08/15/create-a-castle-in-blender-in-60-minutes/
- lots more

Comment: And ... we have a winner !!  Thanks, Steve. Stay healthy

Answer (score 2):

You could always create your castles within [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) for which there are castle creators, online video training and even workshops from English Heritage.

Minecraft is available for a number of platforms including Windows.

Comment: Thanks, Steve (I haven't seen you around for a while on the python questions; I hope that everything is OK). There is even a book on MineCraft castle building [on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Minecraft-Exploded-Medieval-Fortress-Official/dp/0399593217)

Comment: Hi @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - been a bit snowed under the last few weeks - my wife Linda was in hospital for 3 weeks _(nearly fatal gall bladder infection)_ then I have been caring for her since. Of course both of my answers here have an undercover python involvement as scripting for both Minecraft and Blender is usually done in Python. ;-)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I hope that she makes a full recovery soon. Try to get here a Covid jab as soon as it is safe to do so (mine gave em a bad fever for a few days, so they will probably want to wait until she is fully recovered before the jab, but will probably consider here to high risk and therefore eligible. Best wishes (and thanks for the answer)

Comment: p.s any chance of some help on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78526/cross-platform-python-gui-framework ?